# What formula do I use to calculate the force of impact of a falling object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I am trying to calculate the force of impact of a falling object. I did my egg drop project. I dropped the egg from 10m with a mass of 126kg and with the velocity of 14.1 m/s. Which formula should I use to calculate the force of impact?
I found the kinetic energy first and later I used the following formula: $W=Fs$
to find the force of impact. Is that the right formula?

Comment: What you've done assumes that $F$ is constant. To the degree that this is true you're right. Which is the thing about asking for a "formula". They always have assumptions built in and you're never done simply because you looked one up or asked for it: you still have to check the degree to which it is applicable to the situation in front of you. Or at least take an educated guess.

Comment: You did not state how you define $s$. It must be related to the stopping distance. I assume you meant $125 g$ for its mass rather than $kg$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no straightforward way to calculate the force of impact, because this latter is defined by the deceleration of the egg at the end of its journey as a function of time. In turn, this deceleration profile is defined by the elastic properties of both the egg and the surface it hits, and how each of these objects deforms and shatters during the impact. You can calculate the egg's velocity just before impact straightforwardly, but then the calculation becomes complicated by many elasticity and material properties which are probably almost impossible to measure. If you're really interested in the force of impact, it would most readily be *measured*, either:

1. Indirectly, with high speed motion photography of the collision so that you can infer the deceleration as a function of time; or
2. With stress sensors embedded in the impacted surface being sampled at very high speed, which directly measure the force on the impacted surface as a function of time.

Answer (score 0):

In solving this problem if you consider that the air resistance is negligible then you can assume that the the potential energy of the egg just before it is dropped is equal to the Kinetic energy just before it hits the ground. And so you are right to that extent. But the impact of the falling egg would have either created a crater or the egg must have broken in two or several pieces. And we also need to know the number of pieces this egg broke into and the distance that each of these pics have traveled before they came to a halt. only then will you be able to understand the impact of the falling object here. If it has hit the ground then you also should know if the surface is rough or smooth so that we know the effect of frictional resistance.

And the velocity that you mentioned, is it the initial velocity? or the velocity with which the egg hit the ground?

And the mass of the egg - is it in grams or kilograms?

According to me the information provided is insufficient or you need to make assumptions

Comment: Most of this is utterly irrelevant to an egg drop contest because the design goal is to *prevent the egg from breaking*.

Comment: dmckee! Thats not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Simply you can use W=Fs equation. s is known parameter. To calculate force F, we need mass and acceleration of egg. Mass is again known parameter. Acceleration is the acceleration due to gravity, which is 9.8 ms<sup>-2</sup>.

so, W=126*9.8*10 = 12348 J

For given value of force and distance,
[calculate workdone](http://calculatephysics.com/Workdone.html) here.